# Find Payment links by the Price ID

Tags: api, stripe-payments

I created Stripe products, and prices and added payment links to each of them. I am going to use these Payment Links in the future, show them on the site, etc. The PHP backend pulls products, prices, and payment links and shows a pretty formatted picture for the user.

I successfully get products and prices. I didn't find how the [PaymentLink API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_links/payment_links/list) can seek payment links by the price ID. I looked inside the Stripe dashboard and found that it requests payment links in the following way.

> [https://dashboard.stripe.com/v1/payment_links?include_only[]=data.id&price=price_1MWn4sEnbft6LZBGeHuaLVwf&active=true&limit=2](https://dashboard.stripe.com/v1/payment_links?include_only%5B%5D=data.id&price=price_1MWn4sEnbft6LZBGeHuaLVwf&active=true&limit=2)

You can see that it passes the "price" parameter. In the same way, I want to find payment links.

My code

```php
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$data = [];// Collected data
$stripe
    = new \Stripe\StripeClient('sk_test_');
$products = $stripe->products->all([
    'active' => true,
    'limit' => 100
]);

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $prices = $stripe->prices->all([
        'active' => true,
        'product' => $product->id,
        'limit'   => 100,
    ]);

    foreach ($prices as $price) {
        $payment_links = $stripe->paymentLinks->all([
            'limit' => 100,
            // Stripe doesn't have such an option.
            //'price' => $price->id
        ]);
    }

    // Put found info into the $data var
}

print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way of searching for PaymentLinks with a certain price ID as you mentioned. The only way is to [retrieve](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_links/line_items) a Payment Link's `line_items` and search whether an item contains the price you're searching for.